# How to escape only "'" in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

I'm doing something like following to transfer value from PHP to javascript:

```
var str = '<?php echo $v; ?>';
```

If there is no `"'"` in `$v`, it'll just be fine.

But in case there is `"'"` in `$v`, obviously error will be reported.

So far I've only used `mysql_real_escape`, which is not applicable now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to go from PHP to Javascript:

```
var str = <?=json_encode($v);?>;
```

Answer (score 3):

[`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is intended to be only used for value to be used in a string in a MySQL query. Use [`json_encode`](http://docs.php.net/json_encode) to convert your string into a valid JavaScript expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $v = "blah's";
?>
<script language="javascript">
    var str = '<?php echo addslashes($v); ?>';
    alert(str);
</script>
```